# Why do just two elements in a list cease to be recognized after I wrap my code in a package?

Tags: package, common-lisp, infix-notation, infix-operator

I'm getting my feet wet with `defpackage` in Lisp and got off to an ignominious start, namely a bug I can't begin to understand.

The code below is an attempt to create a sublanguage to perform infix operations on vectors. I'd like to use this for a project involving some linear algebra.

The 'meat' of my code is `parse-infix`. This function finds the operator with the highest priority, calls `apply-op` to replace said operator and its operands with `operator (operand, operand)` and thus shrink the list, and iterates until the list contains only the result. Supported operators are the four rules, equality (which binds a result to a Lisp symbol), and vector concatenation.

Here's the code, warts and all:

```
(defpackage :infix
       (:use :common-lisp)
   (:export operator-list
            operators
            parse-infix
            infix))

(in-package :infix)

(defun parse-input (a)
 "Turns symbols into numbers as necessary while reading an expression"
    (if (symbolp a) (symbol-value a) a))

;; Definition of structure containing data for one operator

(defmacro mapf (op type)
 ""
   `(lambda (a b) 
       (map ,type #'(lambda (x y)
                       (funcall ,op x y)) (parse-input a) (parse-input b))))

(defstruct (operator
              (:conc-name op-)
              (:constructor op (sym &key (func (mapf sym 'vector)) priority associativity n-operands)))
            sym                            ; Operator symbol
            func                           ; Function to be applied to operands
            priority                       ; Other operators attributes
            (associativity 'left-to-right) ; Evaluation order for operators
                                           ; that appear more than once in a row
            (n-operands 2))                ; Number of operands (NOT IMPLEMENTED)

(defmacro operator-list (&body ops)
 "Produces an operator list from a list of operator structs."
   `(mapcar #'(lambda (y) (apply #'op 
       (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (if (listp x) (eval x) x)) y))) ',ops))


(defparameter operators
  (operator-list 
     (+ :priority 4)
     (- :priority 4)
     (* :priority 3)
     (/ :priority 3)
     (^ :priority 2  :func expt :associativity right-to-left)
     (& :priority 2  :func (lambda (x y) (concatenate 'vector x y)))
     (= :priority 10 :func (lambda (x y) (set (intern (string x)) y))))
 "Default set of operators, which perform arithmetic operations on
  vectors lengthwise. If one vector is shorter than the other, the result
  is truncated.")

(defun apply-op (b)
 "Reads a segment of a list of the format operand/operator/operand (in 3 consecutive
  cells) and leaves operator (operand, operand) in a single cell."
   (setf (car b) (funcall (op-func (caadr b))
                          (car b)
                          (caddr b))
         (cdr b) (cdddr b)))

(defun parse-infix (b &key (operator-list operators))
 "Parses an infix expression by calling apply-op repeatedly until the entire
  expression is processed."
(let ((expr (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                         (case (type-of x)
                                 (symbol (or (member x operator-list :key #'op-sym) x))
                                 (cons (parse-infix x))
                                 (otherwise x))) b)))
    (loop while (cdr expr) do
        (apply-op (reduce #'(lambda (x y &aux (op1 (caadr x)) (op2 (caadr y)))
                                       (if (or (< (op-priority op2) (op-priority op1))
                                           (and (= (op-priority op1) (op-priority op2))
                                                (eq (op-associativity op1) 'right-to-left))) y x))
                            (remove-if #'listp (mapcon #'list expr) :key #'caddr)))
     finally (return (car expr)))))

(defmacro infix (&rest b)
 "Wrapper to create lists for parse-infix"
   `(parse-infix ',b))
```

And here's the snag. The functions seems to be working...

```
? (infix (#(2 3) + #(4 5)) * #(2 2))
#(12 16)
? (infix (#(100) & (#(2 3) + #(4 5)) * #(2 2))) ; '& is concatenation
#(200 12)
? (infix A = #(5 5) + #(10 10))
#(15 15)
? A
#(15 15)
```

... but when I leave the package, the concatenation (&) operator suddenly 'dies':

```
? (in-package :cl-user)
#<Package "COMMON-LISP-USER">
? (infix:infix A = #(5 5) + #(10 10))
#(15 15)
? (infix:infix (#(2 3) + #(4 5)) * #(2 2))
#(12 16)
? (infix:infix (#(100) & (#(2 3) + #(4 5)) * #(2 2)))
> Error: The value & is not of the expected type LIST.
> While executing: (:INTERNAL INFIX:PARSE-INFIX), in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

I tried to trace the package's functions and noticed that, for whatever reason, '& ceases to be recognized as an operator when I leave the `infix` package. I don't have the foggiest idea why this is the case. Any input is appreciated.

PS. As many probably noticed, all this is in Clozure Common Lisp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short story

`&` is an internal symbol in your package.

You need to export it to fix the problem.

The same goes for `^`:

```
(defpackage :infix
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:export #:operator-list
           #:operators
           #:parse-infix
           #:infix
           #:&
           #:^))
```

## Details

When you type

```
(infix:infix (#(100) & (#(2 3) + #(4 5)) * #(2 2)))
```

while in the [`cl-user`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abb.htm) package,
the symbols `&`, `+`, and `*` are read as `cl-user::&`,
[`cl:+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_pl.htm) 
and [`cl:*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_st.htm).
Note that the latter two are exported from the
[`common-lisp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_aba.htm) package and thus
are also available in your `infix` package:

```
(eq 'infix::+ 'cl-user::+)
==> T
(eq 'infix::+ 'cl-user::+)
==> T
```

However, the first one is different:

```
(eq 'infix::& 'cl-user::&)
==> NIL
```

[`find-all-symbols`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_find_a.htm) is your
friend:

```
(find-all-symbols "+")
==> (+)
(find-all-symbols "*")
==> (*)
(find-all-symbols "&")
==> (INFIX::& CL-USER::&)
```

## PS

Note that I use uninterned symbols as the `:export` arguments
in [`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm) -
so that they are not interned into `CL-USER` by `read`.

Comment: It also might be worth just checking the name of the symbol, rather than the actual symbol identity.  That's what **loop** does.  E.g., you can do `(loop :for x in list)` or `(loop #:for x in list)`, etc.

Comment: Bingo! It's working now. took a slightly different approach, though. I converted the symbols to strings to take advantage of the fact that `(string 'infix:&) == (string '&)`

Comment: You could have used characters instead too.

Comment: @PauloMendes Yes, symbols, strings, and characters are all [*string designators*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator).  The [**string**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_string.htm#string) function returns an equivalent string for all string designators that designate the same string.

Answer (score 4):

**About the code**.

I would propose to use standard Lisp indentation.

not

```
(mapcar (lambda (a)
          a) b)
```

but

```
(mapcar (lambda (a)
          a)
        b)
```

It makes little sense to make `operator-list` and `mapf` macros. Ordinary functions would be better. But: `operator-list` could be a macro, it should get rid of `EVAL`. Using `eval` in macros is a code smell. Often `eval` is not needed or is even the wrong tool.

If you would want to make `operator-list` a macro, then it should expand into code and not use `eval`. You would want it to expand the form into something like:

```
(list (make-operator :sym 'foo :func (lambda (x y) ...))
      ...
      (make-operator :sym 'bar :func (lambda (x y) ...)))
```

Your code expands it into a call of `mapcar`. Which defeats the purpose of a defining macro.

Your code:

```
(defmacro mapf (op type)
  `(lambda (a b) 
     (map ,type
          #'(lambda (x y)
              (funcall ,op x y))
          (parse-input a)
          (parse-input b))))

#'(lambda (x y)
   (funcall ,op x y))
```

is basically just `#'op`.

Which would make it:

```
(defmacro mapf (op type)
  `(lambda (a b) 
     (map ,type
          #',op
          (parse-input a)
          (parse-input b))))
```

Also the naming is not good. `map-something` are functions in Lisp. Functions which map something over something else. Your `mapf` is a macro and it expands into a lambda expression, which as such does nothing - until invoked.

**But, it should actually look like this**

You would want a definition of operators like this:

```
(defops operators
  (+ :priority 4)
  (- :priority 4)
  (* :priority 3)
  (/ :priority 3)
  (^ :priority 2  :func #'expt :associativity :right-to-left)
  (& :priority 2  :func (lambda (x y) (concatenate 'vector x y)))
  (= :priority 10 :func (lambda (x y) (set (intern (string x)) y))))
```

That's the macro:

```
(defmacro defops (symbol &body ops)
 "Produces an operator list from a list of operator structs."
 `(defparameter ,symbol
    (list ,@(loop for (op . args) in ops
                  collect `(make-operator :sym ',op ,@args)))))
```

And this is the code it creates:

```
(DEFPARAMETER OPERATORS
  (LIST (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '+ :PRIORITY 4)
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '- :PRIORITY 4)
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '* :PRIORITY 3)
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '/ :PRIORITY 3)
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '^ :PRIORITY 2
                       :FUNC #'EXPT
                       :ASSOCIATIVITY :RIGHT-TO-LEFT)
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '& :PRIORITY 2
                       :FUNC (LAMBDA (X Y)
                               (CONCATENATE 'VECTOR X Y)))
        (MAKE-OPERATOR :SYM '= :PRIORITY 10
                       :FUNC (LAMBDA (X Y)
                               (SET (INTERN (STRING X)) Y)))))
```

As you can see, there is no need for `EVAL`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough review. Indeed the `operator-list` macro isn't mandatory, and its sole purpose to make the op-lists easier to read. More specifically, I want to avoid lists with 30+ items going `(op... (op... (op... (op... `